# How to draw two intersecting circle holes in graphics?

Tags: flash

I need draw rectangle with two circle holes inside. The problem is in circles interception. I want them to join together and cut from background, but they seems to be XORed:

[image] [image]

At first I tried `drawRect` and `DrawCircle`:

```
graphics.beginFill(0, 0.5);
graphics.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
graphics.drawCircle(width/2, height/2, 50);
graphics.drawCircle(width/2-30, height/2-30, 50);
graphics.endFill();
```

Then I switched to `drawPath`, but no luck too:

```
graphics.beginFill(0, 0.5);
var c1:Object = getCirclePath(width/2-30, height/2-30, 50);
var c2:Object = getCirclePath(width/2, height/2, 50);

graphics.drawPath(new <int>[
        GraphicsPathCommand.MOVE_TO, GraphicsPathCommand.LINE_TO,
        GraphicsPathCommand.LINE_TO, GraphicsPathCommand.LINE_TO,
        GraphicsPathCommand.LINE_TO],
    new <Number>[0, 0, myCanvas.width, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height,
        0, myCanvas.height, 0, 0]);

myCanvas.graphics.drawPath(c1.commands, c1.data);
myCanvas.graphics.drawPath(c2.commands, c2.data);

graphics.endFill();
```

here `getCirclePath` returns object with points to draw polygon which looks like circle. Also I tried different combinations of `GraphicsPathWinding` constants, but no luck.

Any suggestions how to draw two intersecting circle holes in graphics?

Comment: Do you need a vector-based solution or could it be done with BitmapData manipulation?

Comment: Vector-based is preferable, because there is supposed to be tweening and many redraws.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to draw more than one circle without the paths that cross each other "XOR"-ing, you should `beginFill(...)` and `endFill()` **per shapes that you draw**.

I haven't tested, but that would be my guess to properly render overlapping shapes.

**-- EDIT --**

link to demo: http://bit.ly/vBW1ag

How about using blendmodes?

Try to set your scene up like this:

- The container for your rect and the circles has a blendMode of `BlendMode.LAYER`;
- Your rectangle is a child of the container;
- You create circles that are child of the container ABOVE the rectangle, and make their blendMode `BlendMode.ERASE`;

Once you start Tweening them, you should get the animated effect.

See the below example (you can toss it into a new project to see it running)

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.BlendMode;
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.getTimer;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
    private var _rect:Shape;
    private var _circles:Array;
    private var _container:Sprite;
    private var _subContainer:Sprite;
    private var _numOfCircles:int = 2;

    public function Main():void 
    {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        // entry point

        createContainers();
        createRect( 256, 256 );
        createCircles( 40 );

        centerSetup();

        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onUpdate);
    }

    private function createContainers():void 
    {
        _container =    new Sprite();
        _container.blendMode =  BlendMode.LAYER;

        addChild(_container);

        _subContainer = new Sprite();
        _subContainer.blendMode =   BlendMode.ERASE;
        _container.addChild(_subContainer);
    }

    private function createRect(pWidth:Number, pHeight:Number):void 
    {
        _rect = new Shape();

        var g:Graphics =    _rect.graphics;
        g.beginFill(0, 0.5);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, pWidth, pHeight);
        g.endFill();

        /*
         * The canvas that must have the "hole" punched through
         * MUST appear as the first child in the DisplayList.
         */
        _container.addChildAt( _rect, 0 );
    }


    private function createCircles( pRadius:Number ):void 
    {
        var circle:Shape;
        var g:Graphics;

        _circles =  [];

        for (var n:int = _numOfCircles; --n >= 0; ) {
            circle =    new Shape();
            g =         circle.graphics;
            g.beginFill(0xffffff, 1);
            g.drawCircle(0, 0, pRadius);
            g.endFill();


            _subContainer.addChild( circle );
            _circles.push( circle );
        }
    }


    private function centerSetup():void 
    {
        _container.x =  (stage.stageWidth - _rect.width) * .5;
        _container.y =  (stage.stageHeight - _rect.height) * .5;
    }

    private function onUpdate(e:Event):void 
    {
        var circle:Shape;
        var currentTime:Number =    getTimer() * .001;
        var amplitude:Number =      50;
        var direction:int;

        var halfWidth:int =     _rect.width * .5;
        var halfHeight:int =    _rect.height * .5;

        for (var n:int = _numOfCircles; --n >= 0; ) {
            circle =    _circles[n] as Shape;
            direction = (n % 2) == 0 ? 1 : -1;
            circle.x =  halfWidth + Math.cos(currentTime*direction + n) * amplitude;
            circle.y =  halfHeight + Math.sin(currentTime*direction + n) * amplitude;
        }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: So I'll have two **dark** overlapping circles - that's not the desired image.

Comment: Ah whoops, didn't notice that part.

Comment: Added a complete solution that involves BlendMode, but I realize it may not be what you're looking for, however the intersection of circles works and does the "hole" effect you're asking for.

Comment: That's very interesting, thank you! I always forget about blending.

Comment: No problem. If I was to do one extra optimization step, I'd place the circles into another "sub"-container, and only apply the BlendMode.ERASE to that sub-container, instead of each individual circles. At least, optimally speaking... that would make sense I think?

Comment: BTW, demo swf on your site is not loading (at least in my FireFox7).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I wasn't sure which version of the Flash Player you're using in your browser, but I compiled-it down to version 9.0, hopefully it'll now work for you and most viewers.

Answer (score 0):

In Flash, the default winding rule is even odd.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS1EE3740D-F65C-43bf-9B12-74E34D7D1CBE.html

In your second example, add winding to your drawPath based on GraphicsPathWinding:

```
import flash.display.GraphicsPathWinding;

GraphicsPathWinding.NON_ZERO
```

So, this would become:

```
graphics.drawPath(new <int>[/*...*/], new <Number>[/*...*/], GraphicsPathWinding.NON_ZERO);
```

Comment: Does drawing paths handle curves well? How would a circle turn out?

Comment: I tried every combination of `GraphicsPathWinding` parameter in my three shapes. It either draws two dark intercepting circles on rectangle (overlapping or filled together), or two dark XORed circle, or one hole and one dark circle.

Comment: There is no perfect circle in Flash.

Comment: @JasonSturges How's that?

Comment: @BillKotsias Circular paths are approximated by four Bezier paths

Comment: @JasonSturges You are obviously in the know :-) But really I couldn't tell just by the sight of it.